# Vuejs How to render a table based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this `JSON`-array which looks like this:

```
"data": {
   "cells": [
    [
     {
      "rowIndex": 0,
      "columnIndex": 0,
      "value": "<p>This is some value</p>",
      "type": "th",
      "scope": "col"
     },
     {
      "rowIndex": 0,
      "columnIndex": 1,
      "value": "<p>Another value</p>",
      "type": "th",
      "scope": "col"
     }
    ],
    [
     {
      "rowIndex": 1,
      "columnIndex": 0,
      "value": "<p>Blabla blabla</p>",
      "type": "td",
      "scope": null
     },
     {
      "rowIndex": 1,
      "columnIndex": 1,
      "value": "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>",
      "type": "td",
      "scope": null
     }
    ]
   ],
 }
```

Now I want to render this data in a table in my `vuejs`-app, so I tried to do this:

First get the data through computed value:

```
computed: {
    tableData() {
        return this.content.data.cells;
    },
},
```

Then render the data through a table:

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="cell in tableData" :key="cell.id">
        <template v-if="cell.type === 'th'">
            <th v-for="header in cell" :key="header">
                {{ header.value }}
            </th>
        </template>
        <template v-if="cell.type === 'td'">
            <td v-for="celldata in cell" :key="celldata">
                {{ celldata.value }}
            </td>
        </template>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But this shows nothing, the fields are just empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given that the `cells` array contains one array for each row, you must test row type with `row[0].type`
2. Cell content is html, so using interpolation `{{ }}` is not enough - you need to use `v-html`
3. You are using `:key="cell.id"` but I do not see any `id` field in the data itself...
4. You can simplify the template and eliminate duplicity by using special Vue [is](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is) attribute

```js
const data = {
  "cells": [
    [{
        "rowIndex": 0,
        "columnIndex": 0,
        "value": "<p>This is some value</p>",
        "type": "th",
        "scope": "col"
      },
      {
        "rowIndex": 0,
        "columnIndex": 1,
        "value": "<p>Another value</p>",
        "type": "th",
        "scope": "col"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "rowIndex": 1,
        "columnIndex": 0,
        "value": "<p>Blabla blabla</p>",
        "type": "td",
        "scope": null
      },
      {
        "rowIndex": 1,
        "columnIndex": 1,
        "value": "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>",
        "type": "td",
        "scope": null
      }
    ]
  ],
}

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      data
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <table class="table is-bordered">
    <tr v-for="(row, idx) in data.cells" :key="idx">
      <th v-for="cell in row" :is="cell.type" :key="`r${idx}_c${cell.columnIndex}`" v-html="cell.value">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working with JSON data. You really need to parse the json back into javascript datatype first with the `JSON.parse()` method.

You can read up on this on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)